# Make EditText not clickable, but still have focus

Tags: java, android

I have an `EditText` inside a `CardView`.

When the `CardView` is selected, I request focus for the `EditText`, see below:

```
cardProblem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {    
        //request focus                      
        etProblem.requestFocus();
        //display keyboard
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(etProblem, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
});
```

The problem is that I don't want the `EditText` to be clickable (currently when I tap on the `EditText` it gets focus).

I understand that when I don't want it to be clickable, I can add:

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

But in this situation I can't set `focusable` to false because the `EditText` needs focus when I want to edit it.

---

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

---

**I have resolve this**, sort of...
Since I don't have time to waste, I went with the following:

I decided to set the visibility of `EditText` to `invisible` and when the `CardView` is selected I make the `EditText` visible then request focus.

Comment: Add `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` in EditText attributes.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe** it helps you:

create a **fake** `EditText` as a first child in your `CardView` and set the `width` and `height` to **zero** or set **visibility** to `gone`, so he will get the focus by default and the foucus in your **main** `EditText` will be removed and when you need to set focus to it just request the focus :

```
etProblem.requestFocus();
```

Comment: This will not work because if the "fake" `EditText`'s width and height is 0, then it will anyway not be clickable/focusable. When my `Activity` gets created none of my `EditText`'s has focus, I set it programmatically when a `CardView` is selected.

Comment: it will request focus because it is the first edit text in the cardview

Comment: and when I select `etProblem` it will gain focus, leaving me with the same problem.

Comment: i can't uderstand your situation very will but you can when select etProblem request focus to fake edit text

Comment: Please see my edit. Thank you for providing an answer.